# Odd parentheses using elsarticle document class

Tags: citing, natbib, elsarticle

I am generally a user of `natbib` but the `elsarticle` document class (required to submit to a journal) won't allow it so I am using `amsrefs` and faced with a very strange situation. Using the below code:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[author-year]{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

Bundling can be used to incentivise consumers to alter their purchasing habits \cite{Adams1976}. 

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}

\bibliography{Mendeley2}

\end{document}

\endinput
```

Yields the result

[image: Bundling puzzle]

This sort of thing never occurred to me when using `natbib`. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: `amsrefs` is an _alternative_ to bibtex or biblatex not something to be used with a bib file. (It is hardly ever used in practice I suspect) (or if it is used with bibtex it has to be used with its special conversion bib style) (that is one of `amsra.bst  amsrn.bst  amsrs.bst  amsru.bst  amsry.bst`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - The OP's claim that the `elsarticle` document class doesn't allow `natbib` is incorrect.

Comment: I'm wondering if perhaps you tried to load `natbib` with package options that conflicted with the package options used when `elsarticle` loaded `natbib`. That would've generated a warning about an option clash, which might've caused some confusion.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. @DavidCarlisle was correct in that natbib does indeed work with elsarticle; I had to make some additional tweaks to my normal template to make it work (as per Nicola's post).

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> ... but the `elsarticle` document class ... won't allow [`natbib`] ...

On which basis do you make this claim? In fact, the `elsarticle` document class loads `natbib` *automatically* -- a fact which is mentioned on page 1 of the user guide of the `elsarticle` class. One doesn't generally call this a "won't-allow" situation, right? (Were you maybe confusing `elsarticle` with its predecessor, named `elsart`?) Conversely, as @egreg has pointed out in a comment, the `amsrefs` package is not suitable for the `elsarticle` document class -- and hence shouldn't be loaded to begin with.

If you use the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style, just be sure to provide `authoryear` as one of the document class options.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{adams-yellen:1976,
  author = "James Adams and Janet Yellen",
  title  = "Commodity Bundling and the Burden of Monopoly",
  journal= "Quarterly Journal of Econonomics",
  year   = 1976,
  volume = 90,
  number = 3,
  pages  = "475-498",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{adams-yellen:1976}
\section*{References}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd also point out that, on the contrary, `amsrefs` should not be loaded with `elsarticle`.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks, I'll add this to the answer.